# UISearchDisplayController - can see content scrolling behind it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've got a UISearchDisplayController which displays search results in a UITableView that's right below it.

Everything works ok, I'm able to populate the tableview on the UISearchDisplayController, but when I scroll the tableview, the contents of the tableview are shown scrolling up behind the UISearchBar under the status bar of the device.

Has anyone got any experience of how to prevent this from being shown? All of my other view controllers I'm setting the navigation bar to have a specific colour, but on this search controller it doesn't take effect.

Comment: Have this problem now - After making a search - i scroll the table - the search display controller is still active-  the keyboard is dismissed and when I scroll to the edges of the results table i start scrolling the table underneath it and the search results table disappears. were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem if you are using the UISearchDisplayController in a uipopover

I have the same problem and a lot of solutions provided by others do not work.  I am actually quiet close to nailing it now.  It is all about doing a notification to handle the keyboard hide and setting up the search results tableview content size